# Office MS 365 Apps for Enterprise restart withoutsave

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, crash, hibernate

I have Office MS 365 Apps for Enterprise installed and after resuming Windows 10 Enterprise after hibernate the office applications sometimes restart.

This would not be so bad except that the content in the file is not saved making me loose my work.
I have autosave on edit off due to that I do not want to make changes to the file on disk unless I'm ready to do so.

There is no evidence of updates or other.I have tried turning updates off and it still happens.

This have happened for me with Word, Excel and Visio. I don't use the other office app much so that might be the reason that I have not seen the same behavior on those.

Is there any known behavior that would cause this or are the applications just crashing and restart? I have a faint memory that office apps restart automatically after crashing.

Anyone that have see a similar problem or have an idea about what might be happening?

Comment: Is the option "Automatically save my restartable apps and restart them when I sign back in" enabled in Settings? This option is found: In Windows 10 *Accounts > Sign-in options > Restart App*;  in Windows 11 under *Accounts > Sign-in options > Additional settings*.

Comment: No. That option is off.

Comment: What's your computer model? Try [this advice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/all-programs-are-closed-after-waking-up-from/04fd5f83-7a54-4a08-931d-3a2a9f67c1df).

Comment: HP Elitebook x360 1030 G7. It is just office programs that I have problems with.

Comment: Try to [Disable Hybrid Sleep](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001762.htm) and also [Disable Fast Startup](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10).